# How to diagnose and fix routing issue with domain-hosted email

Tags: email, expressionengine, exchange-server

This is not an EE question, though the client does have an EE website :). I just tagged it this way to get the smart folks in the community to see my question.

I have a client who used to have their email and website hosted separately. They were setup with Exchange Server service from one host and regular linux webhosting with another. The way they had it set up initially was their domain was pointed at their webhost and the MX record was forwarded to their Exchange host.  The company from which they were getting the Exchange service through also offers webhosting, so they decided to consolidate. The website was moved to the new account - no problem.  Then we pointed the entire domain, from the registrar level, to the host that had previously hosted only their email. That's where the problems set in.

Now, some emails go through, and some don't - seemingly without any specific pattern. You can send the same email to the same address several times, and some go through and others bouceback.  The ones that bounceback offer some clues - they mentioned the mail server as mail.clientdomain.com - which is not right, as with their Exchange hosting, there is a separate dedicated domain for Exchange.

What it seems like is that in turning on the webhosting component of their account, two things happened - first, a setup of mail.clientdomain.com seems to have been undertaken even though it's not needed.  And then secondly, internal to the hosting architecture, their DNS server is sometimes routing mail through the Exchange server and sometimes running it through mail.clientdomain.com (which of course doesn't work because there are no users set up there, and results in the bounce back).

The main trouble I'm having is telling the host WHAT to fix. I provide them with the symptoms we're experiencing and what I think may be going on, but I'm not well versed in server setup so I can't provide any more direction than i have.  I'm hoping someone out there can give me some guidance on how I can run some tests to see where mail at my client's domain is being routed and therefore provide the host with some specific direction as to where the breakpoint is - because thus far, they have been unable to fix the problem.

Thanks all!

UPDATE: HERE'S WHAT THE RETURNED MESSAGES LOOK LIKE MOST RECENTLY:

Hi. This is the qmail-send program at plesk-vl4.ihost-web.com.
I'm afraid I wasn't able to deliver your message to the following addresses.
This is a permanent error; I've given up. Sorry it didn't work out.

--- Below this line is a copy of the message.

Return-Path: 
Received: (qmail 1553 invoked from network); 2 Nov 2012 07:26:47 -0400
Received: from smtp137.ord.emailsrvr.com (173.203.6.137)
 by webmail.plesk-vl4.ihost-web.com with (DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA encrypted) SMTP; 2 Nov 2012 07:26:47 -0400
Received: from localhost (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
    by smtp10.relay.ord1a.emailsrvr.com (SMTP Server) with ESMTP id 9803F370097;
    Fri,  2 Nov 2012 07:29:55 -0400 (EDT)
X-Virus-Scanned: OK
Received: by smtp10.relay.ord1a.emailsrvr.com (Authenticated sender: jean-AT-qbmarketing.com) with ESMTPSA id 4BD76370091;
    Fri,  2 Nov 2012 07:29:55 -0400 (EDT)
From: Jean St Amand 
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="Apple-Mail=_25EBC7EF-43BA-46B6-94CE-143CA2B87CC2"
Subject: another test email the morning of Nov 2
Date: Fri, 2 Nov 2012 08:32:20 -0300
Message-Id: <56ED44AF-6B20-4627-A53D-1A27E055C2DE@qbmarketing.com>
To: Steve 
Mime-Version: 1.0 (Mac OS X Mail 6.2 (1499))
X-Mailer: Apple Mail (2.1499)

---

The host has said that the system is setup correctly and that the bounce backs are the result of "auto-complete" in our mail programs. But auto-complete only fills in an email address that's been used in the past, not the routing used to get to that destination, isn't that right? If auto-complete played a role in routing, wouldn't everyone run into trouble every time they change web hosts? I've never had any trouble switching hosts in the past, so I find it a bit hard to believe that it's the sender's mail program that's the problem - especially since sometimes the messages do go through, but most often that don't.

Comment: How long has it been like this? DNS issues may take 48 hours to fix themselves.

Comment: [IntoDNS](http://www.intodns.com) is a good tool for checking DNS setups. If nothing else it'll list your MX records which will give you a good idea which mail server is misbehaving.

Comment: What is the domain name so we can look up the DNS settings?

Comment: the domain name is cartenav.com. I used IntoDNS to run a test and i see a couple of odd points but no mention of mail.cartenav.com being part of the routing, even though that's what the bouncebacks referred to.  All of their email is through Exchange and has been through this host since May. It's only when we pointed the entire DNS to the same host that the routing issues came up.  Adrian pointed out that if you do an nslookup on the host's exchange server through their name server, it isn't found. But each can be found directly and other domains can be found through their name server as well.

Comment: Do you know for sure what all the MX DNS records were before you changed the name servers? Did these MX records match: 
MX preference 10 mx1.sherweb2010.com 
MX preference 10 mx2.sherweb2010.com
I think it's unusual to have 2 top preference MX records.

Comment: Could you update your post with a copy of the email headers from a message that's bounced back?

Answer (score 2):

What do the MX records for the domain look like? Is there just the one for "Mail.exchangeserver" or multiples?  Generally they have a score, so the one with the lowest number gets tried first, if that is unreachable/busy then the next in the list gets used.

Another thing to check out, is to see if the web server is running some form of Control Panel that could be getting in the way of mail routing.  I know in the past I've been bitten by cPanel looking locally for mail, even when a remote MX was set up.

If you can post the MX / DNS records, we may be able to help further.

Comment: Just FYI, you shouldn't answer a question with a question. Rather, make comments on the original post and when you have your well formulated answer make your reply. This format is a little different, but it ensure only really well scripted and thought out replies rise to the top, thus making the site more effective.